# Reputation are not grouped by events in the reputation tab - only to me

Tags: support, activity

In my **Activity** -> **reputation** tab, the reputation are not grouped by events. I can remember, previously when a post was upvoted more than one time it was displayed as **n events** with a expandable icon.

But if I view other's reputation tab, I can see the reputation are grouped by events correctly. Also this issue is not occurred in Stack Overflow or other sites. This is strange to me.

Screenshot for reference:

> [image]

Configuration: Google Chrome Version 68.0.3440.106 (Official Build) (64-bit), Windows 10 Pro

Comment: Are you viewing by "time" instead of "post"? It's cropped out of your screenshot but that's my guess.

Comment: @Catija Yes, "time" option was selected, by changing it to "post" I can see with the events.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're viewing with your reputation sorted by time rather than by post. This is how that view works.

It's not necessary to expand each item in the time view because they are each a unique source of reputation. When you sort by post, all different reputation changes are combined for that post, whether that's an upvote, downvote or accept. You need to be able to expand that to see what types of events they were.

When you sort by time, we separate each type of event into a separate item, so the only information that's "missing" is how many of each there were, which you can find by hovering over the event type. So, in your screenshot above, the +139 is actually for 28 upvotes, not the 31 you attribute to it (the remaining three events are the downvotes in the line item above).

[image: screenshot of user's time-sorted content with hover showing total event count]

Note, this screenshot was taken from a non-moderator account, so if you sort other user's reputation pages by time, you should see the same behavior there.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification